# Combining button functionality in anchor tag

Tags: angularjs

I need to combine the functionality of a button in an anchor tag

I'm using AngularJS

```
<div class="text-center" >
    <button scroll-to-bookmark="bookmark1">Bookmark 1</button>
    <a href="#!/details/{{prevItem}}" class="btn btn-left-primary">&lt;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
```

Bookmark 1

If I click the button BookMark1 I go to the  Bookmark 1 with no issue

Objective is their a way of combining this functionality in the anchor tag

Comment: Why not using just the botton?

Comment: The href cycles through an array of items that I want positioned correctly on the screen

Comment: You mean you need two hrefs in one anchor tag?

Comment: no I need the scroll to bookmark functionality in the anchor tag  or the anchor tag functionality in the button